# Birt report - Return requested data and nulls

Tags: filter, null, birt

I am currently building a report with some params one of which im having issues with.

CAST(c.scheduledvisitdatetime AS DATE) >= (ISNULL(?, CAST('1900-01-01' AS DATE)) OR c.scheduledvisitdatetime IS NULL)

I know the line of code above is incorrect but it is just where i currently stand after trying many approaches.

Basically, If a date range is entered then it returns all results within that date range, if the fields are left blank then it should return everything including nulls....why is this causing me so much bother? what am i missing?

Thanks,

Mike.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that line of code. I guess it is SQL? With a BIRT report that uses oracle, I would pass two parameters directly to the db query  this way: `select * from orders where orderdate between to_timestamp(NVL(:fromDate,'1970-01-01'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') and to_timestamp(NVL(:untilDate,'2500-01-01'), 'YYYY-MM-DD');` Guess you are using a different dbms vendor - but it might give you a hint; the query allows at least empty values, dates, and null. If you have items in the database with null as a orderdate, I would try to `UNION` the result with a second query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you MRo for responding.  I actually figured out the answer yesterday, code below for anyone else who may come up against this in Birt Reporting.

```
ISNULL(CAST(c.scheduledvisitdatetime AS DATE), CAST('1900-01-01' AS DATE)) >= ISNULL(?, CAST('1900-01-01' AS DATE))
```

This will bring back anything that is null and with a date when you leave your param filter blank.